# CorePlot: Automatic labeling policy for Date

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I am using CorePlot for an iPhone app. My x-axis consists of dates. I set my refDate like this:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
[dateComponents setHour:12];
[dateComponents setMinute:0];
[dateComponents setSecond:0];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *refDate = [gregorian dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormater = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc]initWithDateFormatter:dateFormater];
timeFormater.referenceDate = refDate;
```

and I set the x-axis like this:

```
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;    
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
x.majorGridLineStyle = majorXGridLineStyle;
x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat(oneHour * 4);
x.minorTicksPerInterval = 3;
x.labelFormatter = timeFormater;
```

When I don't use the automatic labeling policy the graph looks like this:
[image]

Which is fine, but when I zoom in I'd love to have the automatic labeling feature. So when I enable it:

```
x.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
```

I get these results:

[image]

Is there a way to combine my values with the ones form the automatic labeling policy?

Comment: take a look at the CPTAxisDelegate methods, you can get notifications when the graph has been resized and reapply your custom labels at the new scale.